# Akka Camel: Messages routed to incorrect SEDA route

Tags: apache-camel, akka, akka-camel

My simplified `Akka Camel` application is set up as follows:

```
AppleProducer -> seda:appleRoute -> AppleConsumer

OrangeProducer -> seda:orangeRoute -> OrangeConsumer
```

What I am seeing though is that `Apple` events are intermittently being consumed  by the `OrangeConsumer`, and vice versa.

Running this example (perhaps a few times) below recreates it.

I don't understand how this only happens intermittently. What am I doing wrong?

```
object TestApp extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  val camel = CamelExtension(system)
  val appleProducer = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyProducer], "seda:appleRoute"), "AppleProducer")
  system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyAppleConsumer], "seda:appleRoute"), "AppleConsumer")
  val orangeProducer = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyProducer], "seda:orangeRoute"), "OrangeProducer")
  system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyOrangeConsumer], "seda:orangeRoute"), "OrangeConsumer")

  appleProducer ! new Apple("1")
  orangeProducer ! new Orange("1")
  appleProducer ! new Apple("2")
  orangeProducer ! new Orange("2")
  appleProducer ! new Apple("3")
  orangeProducer ! new Orange("3")
  appleProducer ! new Apple("4")
  orangeProducer ! new Orange("4")
  appleProducer ! new Apple("5")
  orangeProducer ! new Orange("5")
  appleProducer ! new Apple("6")
  orangeProducer ! new Orange("6")

}

class MyProducer(route: String) extends Actor with ActorLogging  {

  def receive = {
    case payload: Any =>
      val template = CamelExtension(context.system).template
      template.setDefaultEndpointUri(route)
      template.sendBody(payload)
  }
}

class MyAppleConsumer(route: String) extends Consumer with ActorLogging {
  override def endpointUri: String = route

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case event: CamelMessage if event.body.isInstanceOf[Apple] =>
      log.info("Received event {}", event.body)
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid entity")
  }
}

class MyOrangeConsumer(route: String) extends Consumer with ActorLogging {
  override def endpointUri: String = route

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case event: CamelMessage if event.body.isInstanceOf[Orange] =>
      log.info("Received event {}", event.body)
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid entity")
  }
}

class Apple(id: String)
class Orange(id: String)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to figure this out eventually.

The issue has nothing to do with SEDA. Instead it seems that the same `DefaultProducerTemplate` is returned for multiple `MyProducer` instances.

Therefore, there is occasionally a race condition when setting the `defaultEndpointUri`

Solution, for me, was to create only one instance of the `MyProducer` actor to ensure that we do not encounter this race condition

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend extending the trait `Producer` instead of using a template for your `MyProducer` the same way you are using `Consumer` for your `MyAppleConsumer` and `MyOrangeConsumer`.

```
class MyProducer(route: String) extends Producer with OneWay  {
  def endpointUri = route 
}
```

More info can be found here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/camel.html

I believe you should be able to simplify your code like this (disclaimer: not compiled or tested!):

```
case class Apple(id: String)
case class Orange(id: String)

object TestApp extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()

  val appleProducer = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyProducer], "seda:appleRoute"), "AppleProducer")
  system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyConsumer], "seda:appleRoute"), "AppleConsumer")
  val orangeProducer = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyProducer], "seda:orangeRoute"), "OrangeProducer")
  system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyConsumer], "seda:orangeRoute"), "OrangeConsumer")

  appleProducer ! Apple("1")
  orangeProducer ! Orange("1")
  appleProducer ! Apple("2")
  orangeProducer ! Orange("2")
  appleProducer ! Apple("3")
  orangeProducer ! Orange("3")
  appleProducer ! Apple("4")
  orangeProducer ! Orange("4")
  appleProducer ! Apple("5")
  orangeProducer ! Orange("5")
  appleProducer ! Apple("6")
  orangeProducer ! Orange("6")

}

class MyProducer(route: String) extends Producer with OneWay with ActorLogging  {
  def endpointUri = route
}

class MyConsumer(route: String) extends Consumer with ActorLogging {
  override def endpointUri: String = route

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case CamelMessage(body : Apple, headers) =>
      log.info("Received event {}", body)
    case CamelMessage(body : Orange, headers) =>
      log.info("Received event {}", body)
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid entity")
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to add custom Message creation logic in my Producer (that I left out in the example) so that is why I used the template.